# Add button to nav menu only when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript and HTML5 together,
I have a navigation menu in my website having 3 buttons,

- Home
- Contact
- Register

I have an html form in `Register` page with the `id` called `contact_form`
and I am accessing it in my javascript like this,

```
var regForm = document.getElementById("contact_form");
```

Now I want to show another button in my navigation menu but only if the form is submitted, I can do it using PHP but how can I do it using basic JavaScript and HTML5 only ?.

This is how i can check if the form is submitted,

```
regForm.onsubmit = //do something
```

This is my html for `nav`,

```
<nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                //add one more link if the form is submitted
            </ul>
</nav>
```

and my html form is simple html form with a submit button.

```
<form id="contact_form" class="contact_form" action="submit.html" method="post" name="contact_form">
```

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas, Added the html for navigation.

Comment: @SableFoste, I have added the html

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

When the form starts to submit, you get a submit event. You can run JavaScript in response to to that. That could modify the DOM to add the link to the navigation.

Then the form finishes submitting and you have a new page with a new navigation bar. The previous JavaScript environment has gone away. The new one can't tell that the page was loaded by a form submitting.

This should be handled with server side code (which could be JavaScript but your question implied you were talking about client side JS and that your server side environment was PHP).

Comment: how about if i use `localStorage` and store the form status in the localStorage and show the link in the nav bar ?